# Spring use different bean as per request value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, inversion-of-control

I want to use **specific(Qualified)** bean inside root level bean and beans inside each parent beans, as per information within request object.

Let's say I have specific implement for specific type of request and I am getting decision value at **runtime** (information within request-body object. I need to structurize my code which will full-fill my following requirement.

Consider following sample web example where I need to print B's method if ***identification*** value within request asks for B's implementation and C's method if request specifically for C's implementation. `InputPayload` having identification attribute as `systemType` to decide system specific implementation.

```
----------Controller class---------

@RestController
public class ResourceController {
  @Autowired
  private RootInterface i;   //Class A will be injected here

  @PostMapping(path = "/update", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
  public Result callInterfaceMethod(@RequestBody InputPayload inputPayload) {
    return i.callRootInterfaceMethod(inputPayload);
  }
}

----------Service classes---------

@Service
public class A implements RootInterface {
  @Autowired
  private D d;

  @override
  public Result callRootInterfaceMethod(InputPayload inputPayload) {
    return d.methodToImplement(inputPayload);
  }
}

public interface D {
  Result methodToImplement(InputPayload inputPayload);
}

@Service
public class B implements D {
  @override
  private Result methodToImplement(InputPayload inputPayload) {
    system.out.println("Class B method is called");
    ....
  }
}

@Service
public class C implements D {
  @override
  private Result methodToImplement(InputPayload inputPayload) {
    system.out.println("Class C method is called");
    ....
  }
}
```

If I have no. of service classes and they are injected inside another parent service classes(assume minimum depth of 5). How can use invoke respective service classes instead of using @Qualifier annotation with multiple variable declaration or create different references? How can I call respective implemented method instead of any conditional block?

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- introduce method on D interface which will check if implementation could process input based on input's attributes

  ```
  public interface D {
    Result methodToImplement(InputPayload inputPayload);
    boolean canProcessInput(InputPayload inputPayload);
  }

  //autowire all beans of type D
  @Autowired
  private List<D> dList;

  @Override
  public Result callRootInterfaceMethod(InputPayload inputPayload) {
    for(D d: dList) {
      if(d.canProcessInput(inputPayload)) {
        return d.methodToImplement(inputPayload);
      }
    }
    // if there is no bean that is capable of processing the input payload
    return null;
  }
  ```
- autowire all of the services and add a switch condition for each type of service like this

  ```
  // autowire all beans with their names
  @Autowired
  private Map<String, D> dMap;

  @Override
  public Result callRootInterfaceMethod(InputPayload inputPayload) {
    switch(inputPayload.getType()) {
      case A: { 
        return dMap.get("A").methodToImplement(inputPayload); 
      }
      case B: { 
        return dMap.get("B").methodToImplement(inputPayload); 
      }
      // if there is no bean that is capable of processing the input payload
      default: return null;
    }
  }
  ```

In my opinion, the first option is more clear and scalable

Comment: Primak, idea of having list is good. But I need to pass `InputPayload` or `inputPayload.getSystemType()` to further service classes also and I have depth of 5 service calls in `A`/`B`. And I will prefer not to change method signature for all services.

Comment: Then you can go for the second option with map of beans. It will not change all impacted services, you will have all logic at one place though you need to manually get an eye on this method in case of adding new D services